# How to change matlab list into raster brick in R

Tags: r, raster, mat, r-raster

I have this mat file I get from someone, and I wanted to change it to raster brick in R.

Importing was ok, I was able to import using the `R.matlab` package

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)`enter code here`
library(R.matlab)

SM2RF<-readMat("/..../Nile_DISTR.mat")
str(SM2RF)
    List of 3
 $ lonubn: num [1:231, 1] 34.6 34.6 34.6 34.6 34.6 ...
 $ latubn: num [1:231, 1] 10.12 9.88 9.62 9.38 9.12 ...
 $ Psim  : num [1:8766, 1:231] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN N NaN   ...
 - attr(*, "header")=List of 3
  ..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created  
   on: Fri Dec 19 10:10:41 2014                                        "
 ..$ version    : chr "5"
 ..$ endian     : chr "little"
```

In the lists are the lat, long, and Psim.

I used to raster brick function to convert to raster brick. However, I don't know the structure of the raster in the matlab, and it supposed to be a time series daily rainfall grid for 24 years. But I don't know why, I couldn't identify the number of layers from this  mat file. I tried like brick from array, like

```
r <-brick(SM2RF$Psim, xmn = min(SM2RF[[1]]),xmx=max(SM2RF[[1]]), ymn = min(SM2RF[[2]]), ymx=max(SM2RF[[2]]),crs=CRS("+init=epsg:20136"))
```

However, I find this error.

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : cannot coerce a matrix to a RasterBrick
```

Could anyway help me ? 
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
x <- cbind(SM2RF$lonubn, SM2RF$latubn, t(SM2RF$Psim)) 
b <- rasterFromXYZ(x)
```